# Am I losing resolution after grabbing image of screen then cropping it?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimage

I have some code where I'm grabbing an image of the screen, and then cropping it based on some boundary values:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.mainView.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
[self.mainView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *comicImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(boundary.width, boundary.height), NO, 0.0);
[comicImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(-boundary.xMin, -boundary.yMin)];
comicImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

What I'm wondering is, am I producing a poor quality image with low resolution using the above method? Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Comment: I had the same problem. taking screenshot and cropping it always makes it poor quality. couldn't find any other option.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe,you can use the follow code

```
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
```